# Starting different activities through use of NFC tag not just launch main activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc

I am wanting to be able to open a specific activity through the use of NFC tags.

My mobile application currently launches when a NDEF tag is in contact with Android device.

However I am not sure how I can launch different activities and not just the main activity through different NFC tags. I don't need the NFCs to process any data. Just launch different NFC tags to different activities. (created in Android Studio)

```
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!-- <data android:scheme="http"/> -->

        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".QuizActivity" />
<activity
    android:name=".TicTacToeActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_tic_tac_toe" />
<activity android:name=".HowToPlay" />
<activity android:name=".VideoActivity" />
<activity android:name=".BookActivity" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Just move the intent filter to another activity?

Comment: Did you try to lauch the desired activity from within the onNewIntent(Intent intent) method? There you can check for the data in your NDEF record and decide wich activity to launch.